# navigator.onLine is not working in Firefox, Safari, Opera? Works in IE, Chrome?

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, dom-events

In my chat application I need give a intimation to the user, when the Internet connection is inactive?

So I used the JavaScript **navigator.onLine**, but it works in IE and Chrome. Not in other browsers.

My JavaScript will be:

```
function pingAction(){
    if (navigator.onLine) {
        setTime();
        try
        {
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var checkMsg = xmlhttp.responseText.toString();

                
                    if(checkMsg != "null" && checkMsg.length != 0  && checkMsg != null){

                        var stringToArray = new Array;
                        stringToArray = checkMsg.split("<//br//>");
                        var len = stringToArray.length;
                        for(var i=0;i<len-1;i++){
                            //alert(stringToArray[i]);
                            getText(stringToArray[i]);

                        }

                    }
                }
            };

            xmlhttp.open("POST","PingAction",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("charset","UTF-8");
            xmlhttp.send("userId="+encodeURIComponent(userId)+"&secureKey="+encodeURIComponent(secureKey)+"&sid="+Math.random());
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            alert(err.description);
        }
    }else{
        //alert("offLine   ...");
        document.getElementById("serverMsg").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        document.getElementById("serverMsg").innerHTML ="Your Network connection is failed !";
        document.getElementById("serverMsg").style.display="inline";
    }
}
```

Hope you people will give a good solution.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654579

Comment: @epascarello OMG I forgot about that thread... it might as well have been an emacs vs. VI thread!  I never once personally set my Firefox as "work offline" but I can't count the number of times it refused to hit a website because I needed to turn off "work offline". ho hum...

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for your reply.Its little bit confusing. Is it possible to get the current status of the Internet or not ?

Answer (score 0):

try this `window.navigator.onLine`